# What is the difference between budgeted and non-budgeted parameters for the Hyperband algorithm?

Tags: r, machine-learning, hyperparameters, mlr3

I struggle to understand how the Hyperband algorithm should be set up.
In the book (https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/optimization.html#hyperband), I find e.g. the following sample code:

```
set.seed(123)

# extend "classif.rpart" with "subsampling" as preprocessing step
ll = po("subsample") %>>% lrn("classif.rpart")

# extend hyperparameters of "classif.rpart" with subsampling fraction as budget
search_space = ps(
  classif.rpart.cp = p_dbl(lower = 0.001, upper = 0.1),
  classif.rpart.minsplit = p_int(lower = 1, upper = 10),
  subsample.frac = p_dbl(lower = 0.1, upper = 1, tags = "budget")
)
```

The way I understand the algorithm from the respective [paper](https://jmlr.org/papers/volume18/16-558/16-558.pdf) is that it will:

1. discard some of the hyperparameter configurations (sampled from the search_space) early and that this makes the search much more efficient than pure random search and
2. this applies over the *whole* of the parameter space.

I may misunderstand this as there are some of the hyperparameters "on a budget" (here: `subsample.frac`) and some that are not (here: `classif.rpart.cp` and `classif.rpart.minsplit`). So, what happens with the hyperparamers that have not the "budget" tag? Are they not considered? Or does "standard random search" apply for them (so they may consume as much ressources as they need)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: And as a general rule (for whatever forum you ask such questions), since you are referencing a specific paper you should also include a link - expecting possible respondents to start googling themselves in order to find it is not good practice...

Comment: I included references. The question refers to programming as I need to know how to include the relevant parameters into the ps() function

Comment: The other hyperparameters are randomly sampled in the first stage of each bracket and the budget parameter is set to the `lower` bound value. The best `eta` configurations are promoted to the next stage i.e. the budget parameter is increased by `eta` and the other hyperparameters are unchanged.